# Items in a ListActivity

Tags: java, android

In my ListActivity I have three different options that are clickable. In my "row.xml" I have place an ImageView, but am not sure how to implement it into my Activity so that each selectable item has a different image. Would it be another Adapter?

Here is my ListActivity

```
public class StreamCasts extends ListActivity {
    private static final String[] items={ "item1", "item2", "item3"
    };
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.heroselect);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.row, R.id.label,
                items));
    }
```

Comment: http://tech-villa.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-make-list-in-android-list-view.html   have a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a custom ArrayAdapter that lets you customize the view returned on the overrided getView.

Take a look at http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/  but a general search for 'custom arrayadapter' will give you the start of this.

Get used to it as this is a very common pattern with complicated listviews.